# UWP Extended Foreground Session

Tags: c++, uwp, background-process

So, I have made a few attempts to create an app in UWP, using C++/CX, and besides dreading the syntax, I had *some* fun.
I ran into troubles when I attempted to prevent the app from being suspended. Initially I tried using [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/run-minimized-with-extended-execution) resource, but I have learnt that there is a timeout. Then I tried getting rid of said timeout (though I cannot remember, nor find the exact resource for that).

Finally, I have found the [holy grail](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/run-in-the-background-indefinetly), but it still wouldn't work.

```cpp
    auto ses = ref new ExtendedExecutionForegroundSession();
    ses->Reason = ExtendedExecutionForegroundReason::Unconstrained;
    ses->Description = "Michael";
    auto res = create_task(ses->RequestExtensionAsync()).get();
    if(res == ExtendedExecutionForegroundResult::Allowed)
    {
        ses->Revoked += ref new TypedEventHandler<Object^,ExtendedExecutionForegroundRevokedEventArgs^>(this, &App::OnRevoked);
        MessageDialog^ messageDlg = ref new MessageDialog("Allowed to exec");
        auto sh = create_task(messageDlg->ShowAsync());
        sh.then([this](IUICommand^ comm) {});
        Suspending += ref new SuspendingEventHandler(this, &App::OnSuspending);
    }
```

In this code snippet I am creating an unconstrained session extension, and, if I get permission, I will also display a message box, so I know that it worked.

Both in debug, and at runtime, I have no issues, and the laptop I am running this app on is mostly on battery. But the suspension event is still triggered, and no revoke event is ever called.

I'll provide here both code snippets:

```cpp
void App::OnRevoked(Object^ sender, ExtendedExecutionForegroundRevokedEventArgs^ e)
{
    MessageDialog^ messageDlg = ref new MessageDialog(e->Reason.ToString());
    auto sh = create_task(messageDlg->ShowAsync());
    sh.then([this](IUICommand^ comm) {});
}
void App::OnSuspending(Object^ sender, SuspendingEventArgs^ e)
{
    MessageDialog^ messageDlg = ref new MessageDialog("Suspension event raised");
    auto sh = create_task(messageDlg->ShowAsync());
    sh.then([this](IUICommand^ comm) {});
}
```

My quest, as many others' before, is to find the workaround that will prevent this behaviour, and so my question resumes to this:

How do I prevent an UWP from being suspended, without any regard to the hardware it's running on ( it will run on a PC, be it desktop or laptop), and without a time or resource constraint?

Comment: What's the real problem that you are meeting? I implemented the Extended Execution in a blank app and it works. I added a timer in the Execution and it will write a number into a local file every second. When I minimized the app, the local file could receive the number correctly. The revoke and suspending event will be triggered correctly when the app is closed

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT Even though the app is allowed to execute in the background unconstrained, when I minimize the app, it will get suspended ( it triggers a suspend event and it shows a green leaf in task manager).

Comment: First of all, please do not use the MessageDialog in such events which might cause exceptions in some scenarios. You could use other ways to check if the Extended Execution is working like what I did. Then, please double check if `ExtendedExecutionForegroundResult` is allowed

Comment: I can confirm that the `ExtendedExecutionForegroundResult` is indeed `Allowed`. I have changed the code is it writes to a file, and I did check that it only writes when `Allowed`.
Edit: The app still gets suspended, as it displays a green leaf in task manager.

Comment: What's the OS version that you are tesing? And when will the app get suspended after the app is minimized? Immediately or after 1 min? 2 mins?

Comment: The OS version is 10.0.19042 Build 19042, as for suspension, it's immediate, I've checked the file multiple times, and it stops writing to it as soon as the app is minimized.

Comment: Have you tried to test this demo on other devices? I'm also testing on windows 10 and my sample works correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue, I ended up creating a new project from scratch in c#, and recreating the entire project (luckily I didn't have much trouble, since there wasn't too much to implement). In the end, it might have been something to do with either my xaml or some wrong API call.

Thank you [Roy Li - MSFT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8443430/roy-li-msft) for your time.